# Comment traduire « crazy straw »

Tags: traduction

Je n'arrive pas à trouver une référence en ligne pour la traduction de cet objet :

[image: Crazy straw]

« Paille folle » ?

Comment: https://www.rueducommerce.fr/produit/az-boutique-paille-folle-assortiment-de-50-pailles-5641645

Comment: J'appris une nouvelle expression:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris Moi aussi ! Merci — as-tu trouvé ce site tout simplement en cherchant « paille folle » ? J'aurais dû chercher cette expression au lieu de la suggérer en m'attendant à ce qu'elle ne soit une traduction trop littérale ...

Comment: Yes I found it just by googling paille folle. Should I post my comment as an answer?

Comment: @Dimitris Looking it up myself, I get the sense that it likely is the standard translation, so you can if you want. One never knows what the native speakers will turn up, of course...

Comment: I'm french and I also learned a new expression xD. I had no idea that thing had a name...

Comment: Merchants' websites often use automated translation services... That is just the literal translation. Never heard it either in "real life".

Comment: @Greg > I actually never heard anybody give an exact name to these neither, as you say in your answer there's a great chance any tentative to name it will be followed with an explanation. I'm not sure how "crazy straw" identifies it in English.

Comment: @LaurentS. The English term can be used of any straw that has > 1 bend. [This](https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ZAjjbZj_B1NjSZFHq6yDWpXaI/plastic-drinking-crazy-straw-6-0x200mm.jpg) is a little bit crazy; [this](https://i.etsystatic.com/11386944/c/2209/1754/0/0/il/fe294f/1646055046/il_340x270.1646055046_i0ln.jpg) is crazy though farther from the centre of the concept; and [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_poFGcZJuIKo/SP-0W3OirKI/AAAAAAAAACg/Ec45xYAW8xk/s320/crazy-straw.gif) is prototypical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking it up on some merchant's webites, you can find different names

- pailles à boucles
- pailles bouclées
- pailles fantaisie (although that one can apply to any straws with an unusual design)
- pailles folles (although, I , as a native speaker, have never heard it and would be quite puzzled if someone asked me "peux-tu amener des pailles folles ?" - I suspect it is rather a simple literal translation of the English term that merchants got through Google Translate)

In everyday conversations, I have the feeling (some may argue) that none of these terms will point unambiguously to the type of straws shown in the picture. If someone had to ask specifically for such a straw, they could have to elaborate a bit to be sure:

> Tu peux acheter des pailles à boucle ? Tu sais, des pailles qui font des boucles, et où le liquide passe aussi dans les ronds, comme les enfants aiment bien, pas de simples pailles toutes droites.

Answer (score 1):

Quick googling reveals that you are absolutely right. It is paille folle. All of the links I found though correspond to ads. That is why I do not include any of them.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 En anglais ? Yup, crazy straws were a memorable part of my childhood here in Ontario, even if it was 1/10 having them and 9/10 wishing we were the kind of family that had them more often. I would imagine my friends used it too.